# Triple Modular Multiplicaiton

Tags: math, multiplication, modulus, integer-overflow

I am calculating the following sum:

(a[x]+m*a[x-1]+2m*a[x-2]+3m*a[x-3]+....)%MOD  (MOD=1e9+7)

For this, I am using this loop.

```
long long mulmod(long long a,long long  b,long long c)
{
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (a == 1)
        return b;
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    long long a2 = mulmod(a, b / 2, c);
    if ((b & 1) == 0) 
    {
        return (a2 + a2) % c;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return ((a % c) + (a2 + a2)) % c;
    }
}

res=a[x]%MOD;
for(i=x-1;i>=1;i--)
    res=(res%MOD+mulmod(mulmod(x-i,m,MOD),a[i],MOD))%MOD;
```

However, this is still giving me overflow errors. The basic error, I guess is in (a*b*c)%MOD.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you really trying to find?  `1e9+7` looks like a contest problem (Project Euler, perhaps), and those usually have a sneaky way to back into the answer.  The easy answer, though, is to use your language's version of BigInteger.

Comment: Long long int can't possibly fit in something of the order of the multiplication of 3 really large numbers. So I need to create a function that calculates it.

Comment: mulmod doesn't work right if any of the arguments are negative.  Neither does `res=a[x]%MOD`.  Are you sure that all the a[i] are >= 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to incorporate the following modular arithmetic identities into your program to avoid overflow:

`(A + B + ...) mod C = (A mod C + B mod C + ... mod C) mod C`

and

`(A * B * ...) mod C = (A mod C * B mod C * ... mod C) mod C`

Comment: `for(i=x-1;i>=1;i--)`

      `res=(res%MOD+(((x-i)%MOD)*(m%MOD)*(a[i]%MOD))%MOD)%MOD;`

I have changed my code to this, however the error is still present.

Comment: These lines: `return (a2 + a2) % c;` and `return ((a % c) + (a2 + a2)) % c;` also have overflow potential.

Comment: If I directly use the property of multiplication used above and replace the function with this one line:

`res=(res%MOD+(((x-i)%MOD)*(m%MOD)*(a[i]%MOD))%MOD)%MOD;`

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Shouldn't your `(x-i)%MOD)` term be `(a[x-i])%MOD)`?